# AES-128: How to find cipherkey comparing wrong and right ciphertexts?

Tags: encryption, aes, known-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack, side-channel-attack

I have a .mat file which contains **10 plaintexts and 10 ciphertexts which are correctly encrypted with AES-128 algorithm**. It also contains 10 more ciphertexts which are **wrongly encrypted**. The **fault** is that there is a bitflip in every byte at the input of the last subbyte operation. I also have every single step of AES-128 (encryption/decryption) algorithm in matlab code. My goal is to **find the cipherkey**.

Here are some tips I got, but still I can't find a way to complete my task:

> You can calculate the cipherkey byte per byte cause the last round
>   (subbyte, shiftrows, addroundkey) does modify each byte separately.
>   You can ignore the shiftrows operation cause it does only affect the
>   position. What you have to do is: you guess the key byte, calculate
>   back to the input of the last subbyte operation for both the correct
>   and the faulty ciphertext. Now you can compare them both and check
>   whether the guess of the keybyte was good (think about what
>   characteristics they should have when comparing them). Maybe you have
>   to use multiple pairs of ciphertexts to find one key-byte. After you
>   found the keybyte you can repeat this for all 15 other key-bytes.

I will also attach a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFr16.jpg) of the result I get loading the .mat file.

Do you have any ideas on what to do with the code in order to find the cipherkey?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: By every step do you just mean that you have AES implemented in MatLab or do you mean you have the internal values while encrypting each of the plaintexts?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I have the whole AES implemented in matlab. Both encryption and decryption. Thanks in advance